# Jenkins EC2 plugin cant start node

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins with EC2 plugin and it worked as expected all the time.

Today I decided to enable "Spot requests" feature and after that I started to get this error:

```
SlaveTemplate{description='jenkins-operations-node', labels='Jenkins DEV Node'}. Cannot provision - no capacity for instances: 0
```

Even then I disabled "Spot requests" option - I continue getting this error.
What is the reason - nothing else was changed..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was some bug related to plugin or something else. I started worked as expected again, without any changes